# Extract key-value from JSON having JSON list?

Tags: json, awk, sed, apache-nifi

I need to extract the `id` of `"name":"ConsumeKafka"` from the JSON file textuploader.com/1dchq, so that it gives me the result: 
`"id":"772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6"`.

I cannot use any third party tool due to restrictions. How can I do this using sed/awk?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '[":,]+' '$2=="id" {id=$3} $2=="name" && $3=="ConsumeKafka" {print id}' file
772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6
772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6
772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6
```

- `-F '[":,]+'` - Use any number of double-quotes, colons, or commas as Field Separator.
- `$2=="id" {id=$3}` - If the second field is exactly `id`, save the next field.
- `$2=="name" && $3=="ConsumeKafka" {print id}` - Print the saved id according to fields 2 and 3.

If you only need the first match, do `{print id; exit}`

Comment: Hi @vintnes, this definitely works for the output in pretty-json format. However, when I convert the actual file which is not in pretty format (https://textuploader.com/1dchq), it does not work. So, I tried converting it to pretty-json format using the python tool, ```python -m json.tool```, but it does not work on the converted file either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EdMorton I have fixed the sample. I would have loved to use ```jq``` but it is not yet approved in our organization.

Comment: Understood. And yes python is approved

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EvaluateJSONPath` processor to extract JSON values to flowfile attributes. Use the JSONPath expression `$.processors[?(@.component.name=="ConsumeKafka")].component.id` to extract the `ConsumeKafka` `id` to an attribute on the flowfile.

As an aside, I think the API response you're using is too generic & large to be helpful. You can restrict the information returned in the JSON response to be more specific by making a more specific API call.

Comment: I am in the process of automating deployment in Nifi and hence cannot use another processor. Using REST/Nifi toolkit is the way right now.

Answer (score 0):

From the text file you can do:

```
awk '/"id"/ {print $1}' file
"id":"67e21117-891e-3019-8926-7571b3b0317f",
"id":"67e21117-891e-3019-8926-7571b3b0317f",
"id":"67e21117-891e-3019-8926-7571b3b0317f",
"id":"67e21117-891e-3019-8926-7571b3b0317f",
"id":"a1c4b268-3a6f-3b4c-bf12-0ded10f5d767",
"id":"a1c4b268-3a6f-3b4c-bf12-0ded10f5d767",
"id":"a1c4b268-3a6f-3b4c-bf12-0ded10f5d767",
"id":"a1c4b268-3a6f-3b4c-bf12-0ded10f5d767",
"id":"772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6",
"id":"772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6",
"id":"772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6",
"id":"772658d2-8510-3834-856b-6cfd7e8871f6",
```